# Joomla 3 get the menu title

Tags: php, menu, title, joomla3.0

I'm using multiple menus on one page.
In multiple divs I'm showing a menu (menu1 to menu6). For templating purposes I would like to get the menu title of each menu to show on top. 
I'm not managing to get the title from the menu.

I found this is the way to get the menu items.

```
<?php
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$menu_items = $menu->getItems('menutype', 'menu1');
var_dump ($menu_items);
?>
```

Couldn't be so hard but can't find the right syntax. Who could help me?

Thanks in advance,

Wims

Answer (score 8):

Also you can use this one:

```
$menu = &Jsite::getMenu();
$menuname = $menu->getActive()->title;
```

or if already `$app = JFactory::getApplication();` exist

```
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$menuname = $menu->getActive()->title;
```

Answer (score 4):

The below code works for me in Joomla 3.0:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

$menu = $app->getMenu();
$menuname = $menu->getActive()->title;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
/** Getting the Menu ID of Menu was clicked by user **/
$menu    =   &JSite::getMenu(); 
$id    =   $menu->getActive()->id;

/** Getting the Title of the Menu by using id. **/ 
$db    = JFactory::getDBO();
$query    = "SELECT title FROM kjs_menu WHERE id = $id";
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows    = $db->loadObjectList();
$itemrow = $rows[0];
$title   =   $itemrow->title;

echo "Menu you have clicked is : ".$title;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is not exactly what I ment. 

Iv'e solved the problem bij setting Joomla to show menu titles. In index.php I added style="xhtml":
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu1" style="xhtml"/>
 
In CSS the .moduletable class changed

Thanks anyway. Wims

Answer (score 0):

Since Joomla 3.8 you can use name spacing:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

echo Factory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive()->title;
```