# Joomla 3 get parent title of active menu item

Tags: php, menu, joomla3.0

I found on this thread : [get active menu item title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952199/joomla-3-get-the-menu-title) how to get the title of active menu item :

```
$menu = &Jsite::getMenu();
$menuname = $menu->getActive()->title;
```

but how can I get his parent menu item title?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$parent = $menu->getItem( $menu->getActive()->parent_id );
$parentname = $parent->title;
$parentlink = JRoute::_( $parent->link . '&Itemid=' . $parent->id );
```

Comment: How can I get the parent menu link?

Comment: I needed this for a submenu title and had to add two more variables:

`$menulevel = $menu->getActive()->level;
$activename= $menu->getActive()->title;`

Then I added the title like this: `<?php echo ($menulevel == 1)?$activename:$parentname; ?>`

Answer (score 2):

It's been while since I worked with Joomla, nevertheless give this a try:

```
$menu     = JSite::getMenu();
$active   = $menu->getActive();
$parent   = $menu->getItem($active->parent);
```

Then you can use `$parent` as any other menu item:

```
echo $parent->title;
```

Comment: Just tried but it doesn't work, it doesn't retrieve anything. thx for trying

Comment: How can I get the parent menu link?

Answer (score 2):

What I just used was this:

```
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
$menuname = $active->title;
$parentId = $active->tree[0];
$parentName = $menu->getItem($parentId)->title;
$parentlink = $menu->getItem($parentId)->alias;
echo "<h1><a href=\"$parentlink\">".$parentName."</a></h1>";
```

Found most of this in the Joomla forum and added the alias part, which I guessed ... This works with SEF URLS and URL rewriting on. Anyway, the title line:

```
&JSite::getMenu()->getItem(&JSite::getMenu()->getActive()->tree[0])->title;
```

... which should be the same as what AlexP listed, I didn't check if it's *exactly* the same.

Comment: getMenu() isn't a static method.

The code will work, but it'll give warnings. The correct way to do this in Joomla 3 without getting PHP warnings is as follows:

    $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();